# How to run two applications on the same server and same port?

Tags: angular, express, azure-web-app-service

I have an angular application deployed in azure (working with express in the backend) , inside the angular application (frontend) , I have a seperate folder for a server that establishes an RDP connection to a remote desktop , but the server is running on port 4201 , while my angular app is running on port 4200, so when I deploy the app to azure , the calls to that server don't work. Is there a way to make that server listen to the same port as my angular app ? reverse proxy maybe ?

Comment: Is not clear what you ask... RDP has nothing related to an angular application and you can't use the port of RDP to run also the angular application. You must choose what service must respond on that port

Comment: no , it's not about the azure , I just was explaining why I'm having that server in the frontend.

Comment: So the question is? How to run two angular applications on the same port?

Comment: I know that's not possible , what I'm asking for is an alternative for that , or if I should deploy the server folder separately  to Azure ?

Comment: You can... simply you have to define two project, deploy them in two different folders and use a different base url (one for the first folder and one for the other)

Comment: the problem is that what I need is to deploy just the whole frontend folder that includes the server file and not separate them into two projects.

Comment: The server is generally a web server. Simply build the two angular projects using the ng directives to change the base url and copy the dist content of the two projects in the two choosen folders of the web server. The web server is one, the directories are two, the angular projects are two.

Comment: I was wondering if there's anything I could do in the code to make that happen , instead of the already configured jobs ?